# Error in Sqoop Import statement when running in Windows

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Trying to import from SQL DB to D Drive using Sqoop. Hadoop and Sqoop are installed and configured correctly on Windows. Able to import data from UDB and Oracle database.

Hadoop 2.9.2
Sqoop 1.4.7
DB - Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Sqoop Command -

```
sqoop import --fields-terminated-by ~ --hive-delims-replacement " " --num-mappers 1 --fetch-size 10000 --connect jdbc:sqlserver://<ip-address>:<port-number>;databaseName=<db-name> --username <ID> --password <Password> --table <table-name> --delete-target-dir --target-dir file:///D:\<path> -- --schema <schema-name>
```

have tired different combination in the connect statement, I get below error messages -

Error Msg-1
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: databaseName

Error Msg-2
ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
The port number / is not valid.

Other combinations tired:

```
sqoop import --fields-terminated-by ~ --hive-delims-replacement " " --num-mappers 1 --fetch-size 10000 --connect jdbc:sqlserver://<ip-address>:<port-number>;databasename=<db-name> --username <ID> --password <Password> --table <table-name> --delete-target-dir --target-dir file:///D:\<path> -- --schema <schema-name>
```

```
sqoop import --fields-terminated-by ~ --hive-delims-replacement " " --num-mappers 1 --fetch-size 10000 --connect jdbc:sqlserver://<ip-address>:<port-number>;database=<db-name> --username <ID> --password <Password> --table <table-name> --delete-target-dir --target-dir file:///D:\<path> -- --schema <schema-name>
```